# Object not found! Error 404 in codeigniter project

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

I have seen similar questions asked by other users but none has worked for me. I have a CodeIgniter project which runs perfectly fine in my localhost. I created virtual hosts so that I can host many projects. I do get the first page (login page) of the site but when logging into the system I get the error shown below instead of the next valid page.

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The
>   link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please
>   inform the author of that page about the error. If you think this is a
>   server error, please contact the webmaster. Error 404
>   127.0.0.1 Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3

This is the error log from `www/site/log.../`

```
[Sat May 09 01:10:30.703354 2015] [core:error] [pid 5060:tid 1680] [client 127.0.0.1:57053] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sat May 09 01:10:30.703354 2015] [core:error] [pid 5060:tid 1680] [client 127.0.0.1:57053] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sat May 09 01:10:30.703354 2015] [core:error] [pid 5060:tid 1680] [client 127.0.0.1:57058] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sat May 09 01:10:30.703354 2015] [core:error] [pid 5060:tid 1680] [client 127.0.0.1:57058] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

and my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /accounting/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My virtual host settings:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/saseco"
    ServerName saseco.dev
    ServerAlias www.saseco.dev
    CustomLog "C:/www/saseco/logs/saseco.local.access.log" combined
    ErrorLog "C:/www/saseco/logs/saseco.local.error.log"
    <Directory "C:/www/saseco">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Partial snippet of my login controller:

```
function user_login()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['enter']))  //Login button pressed
        {
            $data = $_POST;
            $check = $this->login_model->login_match($data);
```

Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: What is the URL that is generating this error?

Comment: This is the url for login page. `http://www.saseco.dev/` and the url generated after clicking the login button is `http://127.0.0.1/saseco/login/user_login` @TimBrownlaw

Comment: Why is your `RewriteRule` commented out?

Comment: I was trying to check if the errors are coming because of any of those rules so I commented out and forgot to uncomment it while posting here @ Mike Rockett

Comment: I thought as much - just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in the code you have not shown us - you need to change it where it's creating `http://127.0.0.1/saseco/login/user_login` and make it generate `http://www.saseco.dev/login/user_login` As those are two very different locations according to your vhost setup.

So you would need to have something like `<?php echo base_url('login/user_login');?>`
And make sure that in your /application/config/config.php you have $config['base_url'] correctly configured.
Try

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Or hardcode it to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.saseco.dev/';
```

**Additional:**
Not sure why you have your RewriteBase set to accounting so try changing

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /accounting/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

To

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks @TimBrownlaw, changed the base url which was previously set to `http://127.0.0.1/saseco/' ` to the one you suggested. But it did not solve the problem

Comment: So you cannot get a page if you type in http://www.saseco.dev/login/ into your browser? If not - what about http ://www.saseco.dev/index.php/login/

Comment: `http://saseco.dev/login` results in `Object Not found error`, `http://www.saseco.dev/index.php/login/` displays the login page but when clicking the login button it gives me the `Object not found error` @TimBrownlaw

Comment: Why do you have RewriteBase /accounting/ ? Just have it as RewriteBase / and see what that does for you!

Comment: I have unknowingly copied the .htaccess file of the other project, for saseco the `RewriteBase` is set to `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Your CI Application folder is directly under C:/www/saseco ? No other folders involved? What you'll be finding is that the initial link to your login via index.php is redirecting to a non index.php url... Which points to your htaccess setup ( contents of file / location etc) still being not quite right...

Comment: Do you mean the application folder? If that is what you meant the application folder is under saseco directory and also systems, js etc... folders are there alongside @TimBrownlaw

Comment: Have you been restarting the server when you have been making changes?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?

?>
```

Try this instead:

```
<?php 

?>
```

It worked for me.